# Problem in installing forticlient_7.0.7.0246_amd64.deb

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, vpn

I know there are many similar questions about this problem, but none of them solved my problem.

This file seem to be broken. I have tried to download it several times and every time I faced the same error. Can anyone please show me a clean and clear way to install this VPN on Ubuntu 20.04?

Methods I tried:

https://linuxways.net/ubuntu/how-to-install-forticlient-vpn-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts/
  https://www.fortinet.com/support/product-downloads/linux
  https://devicetests.com/install-forticlient-ipsec-vpn-ubuntu

I got this error message:

```
dpkg-deb: error: 'forticlient_vpn_7.0.7.0246_amd64.deb' is not a Debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive forticlient_vpn_7.0.7.0246_amd64.deb (--install):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 forticlient_vpn_7.0.7.0246_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Problem solved! I should have installed it using :
sudo dpkg -i ./forticlient_7.0.7.0246_amd64.deb